# TooManyPlayerExceptions Deezer API on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, api, onactivityresult, deezer

I'm currently using the Deezer API on an Android app,
and I'm having trouble with the TooManyPlayerExceptions :

```
W/System.err: com.deezer.sdk.player.exception.TooManyPlayersExceptions: Too many players created. Please call release() on unused players.
        at com.deezer.sdk.player.impl.NativePlayerImpl.<init>(Unknown Source:67)
        at com.deezer.sdk.player.DefaultPlayerFactory.createPlayer(Unknown Source:9)
        at com.deezer.sdk.player.AbstractPlayerWrapper.<init>(Unknown Source:23)
        at com.deezer.sdk.player.TrackPlayer.<init>(Unknown Source:0)
        at fr.cordier.duels.Choice.onCreate(Choice.java:85)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
```

I understand what the problem is, I can't create more than 4 or 5 players, and I always call the release function. But my issue is that I invoke and finish the activity where the TrackPlayer is created quite often, and I create the TrackPlayer in the onCreate. So, when I call the activity for the fourth time, the app crashes because of this issue.
Here is the code of the onCreate of the activity where I create the player (it's a startActivityforResult, that's why I need to finish it at the end).

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_choice);

       


        //Player Deezer
        DeezerConnect.forApp("423942").withContext(getApplicationContext()).build();
        try {
            trackPlayer = new TrackPlayer(this.getApplication(), deezerConnect, new WifiAndMobileNetworkStateChecker());
        } catch (TooManyPlayersExceptions tooManyPlayersExceptions) {
            
            tooManyPlayersExceptions.printStackTrace();
        } catch (DeezerError deezerError) {
            deezerError.printStackTrace();
        }


        //Récupération des matches
        Intent intent=getIntent();
        String nbre=intent.getStringExtra("nbre");
        final int val=Integer.parseInt(nbre);
        posV=new int[val/2];
        preview=new long[val];
        songs=new ArrayList<>();
        final int[] num=new int[val];
        for(int i=0;i<val;i++){
            songs.add(intent.getStringExtra("song "+i));
            String value=intent.getStringExtra("pos "+i);
            songURL.add(intent.getStringExtra("info "+i));
            String idS=intent.getStringExtra("preview "+i);
            Log.i("test",String.valueOf(idS));
            preview[i]=Long.parseLong(idS);
            num[i]=Integer.parseInt(value);
        }

        k=1;
        match(songs,val,num,k);
        selection(num,val);
    }
```

Thanks a lot for your help, I hope this question will help some of you if you have the same issue!

Answer (score 0):

Please add this below method under onDestroy() method

```
private final void disconnectFromDeezer() {
    // if deezerConnect is still valid, clear all auth info
    if (mDeezerConnect != null) {
        mDeezerConnect.logout(this);
    }
    
    // also clear the session store
    new SessionStore().clear(this);
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for your help, but I still have the issue :/ It seems to logout from Deezer indeed, but I still have the error message the fourth time I invoke the onCreate and I create the Player.

Comment: May I know where you call this method in activity?

Comment: The "disconnectFromDeezer" or the "onCreate"? For the first one, I call it inside the onDestroy method like this `@Override protected void onDestroy(){ super.onDestroy(); disconnectFromDeezer(); } `.   For the onCreate, I call it with StartActivityOnResult within another activity.

Comment: Please call this method onStop()

Comment: You mean call the disconnectFromDeezer within the onStop() method? It doesn't work neither, same issue than the one with the onDestroy. I hope it's not a limitation from Deezer to avoid connexion/trackplayer issue